# Use Live App inside a spreadsheet

Tags: quip, liveapps

Can I make my live app insertable inside a spreadsheet or table cell?

Is there any other way to power a spreadsheet cell with data pulled from an API? I know about the automation API, but my use case is closer to having the user insert some data into a doc and then get data pulled from an API, rather than having some external process call the automation API.

Answer (score 0):

Live Apps are their own sections, so they cannot be inserted in a spreadsheet cell - but you could use a Live Apps Auth to connect to Quip via OAuth, then perform actions on behalf of the user by calling platform APIs as you suggested. The platform APIs are currently the best way for developers to change spreadsheet content.